# Angular 2.0 setup

Tags: angular

how to setup the environment for Angular 2.0 in Visual Studio 2013? I had tried so may ways but few dependent like "node_modules/angular2/bundles/typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" is missing.Kindly let me know the complete setup for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best way forward is to read the documentation, work through the tutorials, and perhaps take one of the many good online courses available for Angular development.

Free Docs / Tutorials:

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

For Pay:

https://ultimateangular.com

https://teamtreehouse.com

StackOverflow is where you'll come to ask questions when you've got a project started and specific code that you can share and ask questions about, it's not really intended for broad sweeping 'where do I start' questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. ill try with this